# NSPredicate returning all objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm trying to use the `NSPredicate` to only get specific objects. The problem is that all the objects are fetched and it should only be specific objects where the condition is correct.

```
- (void)fetchDevices {
    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Songs"];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Songs" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    // retrive the objects with a given value for a certain property
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"selectedRow == %@" , selectedRowNumber];
    devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

}
```

The `selectedRowNumber` is an `int` declared in the `.h` file.

A look on my Songs entity:

[image]

PS. Please comment below if more information is required and i'll provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the predicate *before* executing the fetch request.

Also, if `selectedRowNumber` is an `int` then you have to use the `%d` format
instead of `%@`.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"selectedRow == %d" , selectedRowNumber];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of setting Entity using `setEntity`.

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]
```

Just set predicate, it will work.

```
- (void)fetchDevices {
    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Songs"];
    // retrive the objects with a given value for a certain property
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"selectedRow == %@" , selectedRowNumber];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"selectedRow = %@" , [NSNumber numberWithInt: selectedRowNumber]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be two problems.

1. I think you need to put `[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];` before  `devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];`
2. Also `@"selectedRow == %d"` seems not right. You may want to change it to `@"selectedRow = %d"`
3. And no need to set entity again.

So the code may look like this.

```
- (void)fetchDevices {
    int selectedRowNumber = 1;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Songs"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"selectedRow = %d" , selectedRowNumber];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]     mutableCopy];
}
```

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: You can use `==` or `=` in a predicate, it does not make any difference.